# Syncing iPhone 3G with iCloud

Tags: icloud, iphone

Was wondering whether it's possible to sync non-iOS5 devices (in this case iPhone 3G) with iCloud? In particular I'd be interested in syncing contacts.

I know syncing iCloud e-mail won't be much of a problem, as it can be configured as a standard IMAP account, but what about the contacts? Does contacts syncing go via some standard protocol that iPhone 3G with appropriate settings could use?

Comment: There is a discussion about this ongoing on http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1176780, I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 4):

Its easy:

Go to: setting > Mail, Contacts, Agenda   and "add a new account".
Choose "other"
Then add "CardDav-accounts" under "contacts" tab

In the server field first fill in: contacts.icloud.com
Then you apple id and password, then add or save account.
Then the server address will change to something like:  p02-contacts.com

Next step is to know what unique apple ID you have, you can find it here on your mac:

`~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources/<iCloud Account ID>/Configuration.plist.`

Now, go back to the just created account on your iPhone for your contacts and change the server address field.

Contact server: `https://p02-contacts.icloud.com:443/<uniqueid>/carddavhome/`

You have to add everything above, so `https://<your correct server>:443/<your uniqueID>/carddavhome/`

Before you do all this you have of course setup iCloud and make sure that you have address book checked. Also make sure you have deleted your MobileMe account on the iPhone first if you have one.

It might take some time but it will work.

Comment: The / after carddavhome is very important. If you leave it off it will not sync.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, leaving off the https, and adding /[contact group] after carddavhome.

Didn't seem to work without the /[contact group]. No idea why.

Still gave me all contacts, and all groups, but allows me to select the iCloud contact group I wanted (a phone specific group of contacts).